# My code doesn't print what I want it to print

Tags: python

If the number is 1 want it to print `1 is a number` but instead it prints `<function num> is a number`. How do I fix this?

```
def num():
  int(input("number: "))
try:
  num()
except ValueError:
  print(f"{num} is not a number")
else:
  print(f"{num} is a number")
```

Comment: `num` is a function, try returning a value from the function and assigning it, that won't help with the value error though

Comment: And at what point would you think is `1` passed to the `print`?

Comment: in num func you need to return the value then get it as `num = num()`

Comment: You will need to assign the original `input()` to some variable. If it's not a valid `int`, currently there's absolutely no way to access it, since it's passed right through `int` and is lost if that raises an error…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Functions as Value

In python functions are also values, so name `num` is bound to the function that you defined in the def statement. That's why when you `print(num)` you get `<function num>`. Assigning the return value of your function call to `num()` will solve the problem for the print statement you asked:

```py
def num():
  int(input("number: "))

a = num()
print(f"{a} is a number")
```

### Exception Handling

However, as you can see you, if you use the same `try except` structure that you used and assigned `a` under the `try:` statement, you wouldn't be able to access it under the `except` statement. Why? Because this is very bad exception handling design. The exception is raised by the call to `int` with a "non integer convertible" value, and thus it makes a lot more sense for you to handle it under the definition for num where call to `int()` is made:

```py
def num():
    a = input("number: ")
    try:
        b = int(a)
        print(f"{a} is a number")
        return b
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{a} is not a number")

num()
```

Although this fits your needs, exception handling under the same function is not absolute, and in many cases you might want to pass exceptions around in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an input and output in your function.
you can try something like:

```
def is_one(num):
  #if number is 1 return True otherwise return False
  return num == 1
if is_one(num):
  print(f"{num} is a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

do below:

```
def num():
    try:
        input_value = input("number: ")
        input_value = int(input_value)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{input_value} is not a number")
    else:
        print(f"{input_value} is a number")

num()
```

from your query it seems like you are not intereseted in any return value from your metgod hence move your exception handle within your function and you should be good else return a input value from your method and then do exception handle. Hope this makes sense.